# Way distinguishing whether or not complex manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

$SU(3)$ has dimension 8. Why is this not a complex manifold ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the unitary group is defined by non-complex-analytic equations (i.e., $AA^*=I$). Moreover, the only connected, compact complex submanifold of $\mathbb C^N$ is a point.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I understand little. (1) I do not know non-complex-analytic equation. It provide nonexistence of complex structure ? (2) Embedding of ${\bf CP}^n$ into ${\bf C}^N$ is not complex manifold ?

Comment: This answer shows that the natural inclusion map $SU(3)\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^9$ is cannot be holomorphic for any potential complex structure on $SU(3)$, but doesn't rule out an abstract complex structure on $SU(3)$ as a whole.  Do you know of an argument that does?

Comment: Any function involving $\bar z$ nontrivially is NOT holomorphic. By what I said earlier, you cannot embed $\mathbb CP^n$ in $\mathbb C^N$.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: The only compact complex Lie groups are tori. Or are you not going to allow a Lie group structure, either? :)

Comment: :-)  (Sure, let's do this with both hands tied behind your back!)  Of course, this only shows the group operation cannot be analytic with respect to any complex structure.  I do seem to recall somewhere on this site where someone lays down the proof, but I'm currently having trouble finding it...  +1 from me anyway.